# BUTTON LABELS in Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

Can someone tell me how to dynamically change the button label during run time?

Here is the code i tried:

```
var go:Button = new Button();
go = symbol_1;
go.label = "GO";
```

This does not seem to work.

The error stated is "Access of possibly undefined property label through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton"

Comment: seems to me that the Button doesn't have a property label.

Comment: Can you then please tell me how to set and change the text on a button during run-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're doing it the wrong way. If you say `var go:Button = new Button();` you create a new `Button` object and then assign another object to `go` variable. So the new `Button` you created has been lost, there are no references to it, therefore there is no need to create a new `Button` in this situation.

Second, your `symbol_1` is of type `SimpleButton` as it's clear from the error. `SimpleButton` objects do not have `label` property, that's why you're getting an error when trying to assign to it.

Now for the workaround. <strike>You can either place a `TextField` in your `symbol_1` and give it an instance name, which you will then reference like this:</strike>

```
// assuming that instance name for the placed TextField is 'textBox'
symbol_1.textBox.text = "new label";
```

**EDIT:** Actually go for the second method described below as this first one is buggy and not dependable.

Or I'd recommend you make your own class based on a `MovieClip` which has a label property and can change it without much hassle.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Cant vote up your answer thanks to my low reputation :(

Comment: No problem, but now when I tried putting a `TextField` in a `SimpleButton` I get errors when assigning a new label. So go for your own button class.

Comment: I converted the symbol into a movie clip and here there is no problem in using label.

Comment: Yes you can do that. But it'll give errors if you try to reference a `TextField` inside a `SimpleButton`.

Comment: @Arjun Bala you can not vote but you can(have to) accept answers if the answer solves your problem.